Do courts distinguish between an act being a "material contribution" and a "material increase in risk" in negligence claims?
Fact: In the UK, a claim for harm suffered as a result of the tort of negligence can be made against one party even when there are multiple causes of the tort as long as there is a material contribution by that party (see: Bonnington Castings Ltd v Wardlaw [1956]).

This is straightforward to interpret when both parties are known to have contributed to the claimant's harm.

Question: But what if the cause is not known and there are multiple individuals who all increase your risk of harm without it being known who actually caused you to experience the harm?
In other words, what is the difference between how courts treat a material contribution to harm versus a material increase in risk of you experiencing that harm in tort claims?

Example to illustrate: C works with chemicals and argues that his employer, D, has caused him to experience a skin condition due to negligence. Upon examination, a medical expert says this could have been caused by C cleaning their home with bleach without gloves. The medical expert says that it is possible that one or the other caused the harm suffered, but not both (though they both increased the risk of harm). Could D rely on the defence that even though they materially increased the risk of the condition, there is no evidence that they were a material contribution to that harm?

How could it be "not both"? Coal mining and smoking both increase the risk of cancer. How could an expert say that a smoking coal miner's cancer was caused by only one of the factors?

If you're poisoned and then shot, a doctor might be able to say that the gunshot was the proximate cause of death. But you might have died from the poison anyway, or the poison weakened you so you couldn't recover from the gunshot.

If we assume that both were done over a long period of time, then we could reasonably say that both materially contributed to damaging the claimant's lungs and (more generally) their body. You're right we can't directly attribute the cancer to one, but both materially contribute by making the situation worse @Barmar

Let's say for argument's sake that it was the coal mining that caused the cancer. Yes, smoking didn't cause it, but it certainly would be a material contribution for it being worse @Barmar

But you don't know which was the straw that broke the camel's back, is that the issue?

Assume there are two possible defendants A and B and if one caused the harm, then the other is entirely innocent. In the smoking vs coal mine example, neither would be innocent. Regardless of which broke the camel's back, both can be said to have materially contributed to the damage the claimant has suffered. If they hadn't have done one of those two things, they would have suffered less harm @Barmar

A better example would be where the claimant ate two meals and ended up severely unwell. Upon medical examination, the doctor found that there was definitely food poisoning but it is impossible to tell which of the meals was bad. Could you still sue either party? Even though there is a 50% chance that whichever one you choose is entirely innocent  @Barmar

(this is not the case in your smoking/mining example since neither is entirely innocent in either causing cancer or making it worse through the damage it has already done to the body)

These examples don't seem to fit the question. In the food poisoning example, you would try to get samples of the food from both meals, and test them to see which one was bad. While either one could have been bad, only one of them actually was, and you can only sue that chef.

The idea behind the question is that we are talking about scenarios where it is impossible to know which one it was. Let's say that there is evidence of bad food hygiene practices by both chefs, but only one of the meals has caused the food poisoning. For there to be a valid negligence claim, you need to establish that the negligence lead to harm. Without knowing which one actually caused the harm, is it still possible to make a valid claim for your harm suffered? @Barmar

If you've not tested both meals, then both of them could have been bad.

That's true. But the point I was making is that we could be suing a completely innocent party. This would be different from a situation where both were known to contribute in some way (where both parties were guilty, at least to some extent) @TripeHound

This doesn't seem like a case of "multiple causes" that contribute to the injury. There are multiple possible causes, but only one of them actually caused the injury, and you don't know which it is.
But in court, you need to prove that the defendant actually caused or materially contributed to the harm. It's not enough that they could have contributed. If it's impossible to know which individual caused the harm (e.g. all the evidence was eaten), then I don't think you have a cause of action against any of the potential defendants.
However, you could potentially sue all of them. This will allow for discovery so you can determine which one was actually at fault. Once you narrow it down, you could drop the cases against the others. But those defendants may be able to collect legal costs from you.

I think this + your comments address my issue. Although, my guess would be that courts would be reluctant to accept that there has been a material increase in risk, but not a material contribution unless it is absolutely clear that they must do this

I don't think there's either, I think you're looking at this the wrong way from the outset.

I think it depends on the problem. In the chemical handling example, it feels as though courts would likely find that both are material contributions, even though only one caused the condition (since are harmful).

Do you agree or do you still think I am looking at this the wrong way? If so, I would appreciate it if you could clarify further

Right, which is why the examples matter. If it's the poisoning example, only one of them was in the causal chain at all. But in the chemical handling or smoking miner examples, everyone contributed to the risk.

And when everyone contributes, the final result may only be due to the combination, not one or the other.

In the case of McGhee v National Coal Board [1972], the claimant was exposed to coal dust in their work. The workplace had no washing facilities and so the claimant had to go back home to wash. Being exposed to coal dust at work was part of the job, but the employer was still find liable for the claimant suffering dermatitis because the longer coal dust is on your skin, the greater the chance you have of getting dermatitis and so by not providing shower facilities, they materially increased the risk of the claimant contracting dermatitis (even though they may have got it anyway)

And so by making the claimant travel home, the coal dust was on the claimant's skin for long enough for it to have materially increased the risk of dermatitis

That's not a case of "impossible to know which one it is". They concluded that it's far more likely to be caused by the coal dust.

From Wikipedia: "there was no evidence to suggest that without the defendant's negligence the plaintiff would have avoided contracting dermatitis. Consequently, the decision has been criticised as creating a "legal fiction" by equating the defendant increasing the risk of harm with a causation in fact."

Apparently the court/jury at the time didn't feel that way. But mistakes happen.

FYI - I have no idea how much more likely the lack of washing facilities made dermatitis. The job involved exposure to coal dust anyway, so being caused by the coal dust is of course almost certainly the cause. The question is whether it was caused by exposure to coal dust while working (not negligence) or additional exposure to coal dust while travelling home to shower (negligence) is what was being considered

Sometimes courts work backwards: They have a verdict they want to impose, and they'll find some way to interpret the law such that it supports that verdict. That's often where "legal fictions" come from. SCOTUS apparently did something similar when they found Trump mostly immune from prosecution.

More generally, you can't treat the law as black and white. There are lots of shades of grey and judgement calls.

The claimant must prove causation
Remember that in a civil trial, the burden of proof is on the balance of probabilities.
For your example, C must provide evidence that there was a causal link between D's acts or omissions and the harm that C suffered. Such evidence can be circumstantial. For example, smokers have been able to prove by epidemiological expert evidence that their lung cancer was legally caused by smoking, even if that would not amount to a scientific standard of proof. Scientifically, it has been proven that smoking increases the risk of lung cancer, but it cannot be proved that any particular lung cancer was caused by smoking.
Contributory Negligence
D could argue, probably successfully, that C's own actions also contributed to the harm. If they succeed, the court will reduce the damages payable by the proportion that C contributed to the harm.
Proportionate Liability
In some jurisdictions (not the UK AFAIK), statute law has introduced proportionate liability as a defence.
If D can identify other wrongdoers (for example, the chemical company that made the toxic home bleach) and show that they were also at fault, then D's liability is reduced. Not that this is a defence for D - it doesn't make those other parties liable to C unless they were joined in the action against D.

Without wishing to make this too mathematical, but does this mean if D increases C's risk of harm from, let's say, 20% to 50%, then since the probability that D caused the harm is (0.5 - 0.2) / 0.5 = 60%, this means that a jury would find in C's favour

@FD_bfa no, it means that if D caused 80% of the harm and C caused the rest, D would have to pay 80% of the damage.

For example, does your point hold up if D increases C's risk from 20% to 21%? 25%? 30%? Etc? My argument is that if D increases C's risk by X%, then the judge should only decide in C's favour if X / (X+0.2) > 0.5 since this left hand quantity is the probability that D caused the harm and by being greater than 0.5, this meets the standard of proof required for D to have caused the harm

Also - I'm not sure that D would be said to have caused 80% of the harm in the above example either. Since increasing the risk of harm from 20% to 50% means that, on the balance of probabilities, D caused C to suffer the harm, doesn't this just make D 100% liable for the harm, since the probability that D caused the harm is beyond 50% (of course it could be reduced to 80% if the 20% was due to to contributory negligence, but we aren't assuming that's the case)

@FD_bfa it has nothing to do with increase in “risk”. It has to do with the proportion of actual harm caused.

I agree. But if C has a 20% chance of getting cancer and D increases that to 50%, then that doesn't mean that if C gets cancer that 20% of their harm was not caused by D

If on the balance of probabilities C wouldn't have had cancer without D (ie. 0 harm) but thanks to do now on the balance of probabilities they will have cancer (100% harm), then isn't D just 100% liable?
